# Use of a commoner's talis to read the Torah on

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, tallit-gadol, sefer-torah, simchat-torah

*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 153:21:

> אין לקנות מעילים שנשתמש בהם הדיוט לתשמיש קדושה
>
> One must not purchase for holy use garments that a commoner used.

"Holy use" here includes use as the cloth cover of a *sefer Tora* (*Rama OC* 147:1). One cannot, therefore, buy someone's poncho for covering a *sefer Tora*.

Does this *halacha* (as is sort-of implied by its wording) apply only to an object that will be used long-term, or regularly, for a holy use? Or does it apply even to an object that will be used, say, once for a holy use: one should not take someone's poncho and use it even once to cover a *sefer Tora*? A sourced answer would be ideal.

Now, a cloth the *sefer Tora* rests on also is considered to have a holy use (*Bavli*, *M'gila 26*, "כיון דחזינא דעייפי ליה ומנחי סיפרא עלויה אמינא תשמיש קדושה הוא"). So, if the answer to my first question is "it applies even to something used once", then how do we take someone's *talis* and lay it out for a *sefer Tora* to be read on (as is frequently done on *Simchas Tora* and in a mourning house)?

Comment: I don't see what the question is. The reason one may not use a commoner's clothing for holy use, is (as the Mishna Berura explains 147:12) because that is not considered respectful. Why would a tallis shel mitzvah fall into that category?

Comment: @Michoel, because it's not respectful to use something a commoner wore (even for a _mitzva_) for a holy use? (Note that a holy use is a 'higher' use than use for a _mitzva_ is: see, e.g., _MB_ 147:13.)

Comment: I would be inclined to think that something that was used for a mitzva does not fall under this category. On the contrary - ["הואיל ואתעביד ביה מצוה חדא נעביד ביה מצוה אחריתי"](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%98_%D7%91)

Comment: Is the following another valid translation? "Do not use for holy purposes garments that we use for common purposes."

Comment: Your quoted text says "purchase", not "borrow" or "rent".  How significant is that?  (It implies longer-term/permanent use, versus a one-time thing, to me.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, that's what I meant by "as is sort-of implied by its wording" (in the question).

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman not AFAICT.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, and I think the reason why is that there might be too much being asked here. Some underlying principles might need to be asked as starter questions. 1a. Why does use by a commoner make it ineligible for use for a holy purpose? 1b. Based on 1a, does a single use by a commoner gain it that status (depending on the answer to 1a, the answer the 1b might become obvious). 2. Does the prohibition from use for a holy purpose extend to a single holy use or only permanent designation (or _Davka_ a single use and _not_ permanent designation)? (This may also depend on 1a.)

Comment: @SethJ, thanks for the analysis. Your "1b" is of no concern to me, and your "2" is the first of my two questions. Your "1a" may well be relevant to your "2", and if I don't get an answer to the latter here, perhaps I'll ask your "1a" as a separate question.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53320/5323

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93375/170