# Can a Torah be laid on a bare table?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, torah-reading

When people read or roll a Torah, I have always seen the table covered either with a cloth or a tallit. Is it necessary to cover the table? Why? If not, and this is a minhag, what is its source?

Could the reason be because of what is said in Talmud Bavli Megillah 32. ? -

> "Rabbi Parnach Rabbi Yohanan said that one who handles a Torah bare
>   (without a cloth) is buried bare ... Abaye explains this as meaning
>   "bare" without this mitzvah."

This is referring to handling a bare Torah. Would that include laying it on a bare table?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe it's just a sign of respect?  After all, the Torah itself is treated as an object/representation of royalty, being decorated and the parchment itself being untouched by human hands, the Congregation standing when the Ark is opened/closed and it's being handled, etc.  You wouldn't have a Royal Decree from the King placed onto and read from a normal piece of undecorated furniture that was otherwise used for changing the baby's diapers or stacking tools or ...well, anything else on, would you? Once again, I'm sure other folks here know the appropriate references for this..

Comment: @DanF A siddur doesn't have the same level of Kedusha that a Sefer Torah has.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19128/170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not strictly necessary, it is done in order to avoid making the table a *tashmish kedusha*. A *tashmish kedusha* may not be discarded and must be buried ([*genizah*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/genizah-storage/info)) ([OC 154:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x535), [YD 282:12](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6797)). Placing a cloth over the table ensures that the table (even if the table was designated for this use, such as the *bimah* in *shul*), will only be a *tashmish d'tashmish*, and permitted to be discarded ([Megillah 26b](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=26b&format=pdf)), while the cloth (if designated for this use) will become a *tashmish kedusha* (see Rashi [Megillah 26b](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=26b&format=pdf), Taz [YD 282:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6797)). However, if the cloth (or *tallis*) is only used temporarily, then the cloth was never designated to be a *tashmish kedusha*, and is therefore permitted to be discarded (See *Beis Yosef* [YD 282](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6341)).

Comment: Is just using something temporarily really enough to make it a tashmish Kedusha? You have plenty of sources for what to do with tashmishei Kedusha but no source for your actual answer

Comment: @DoubleAA The Taz says so

Comment: So if you ever put your Megillat Esther down on a chair for a second before wrapping it back up you have to bury the chair??

Comment: @DoubleAA Does a Megillat Esther have the same holiness as a *Sefer Torah*?

Comment: I mean you can't put a Chumash on a Navi, but it's still a Cheftza of Kedusha and it has Tashmishim.

Comment: @DoubleAA I reread my answer and I don't see where I mentioned anything about being temporary. In any case, it would seem from that Taz that even temporarily placing a [bare] *Sefer Torah* on a chair would make it holy and you would have to bury the chair. That being said I don't know if a Megillat Esther has the same status that would render anything it temporarily rests on a *tashmish kedusha*. I have seen that people are **not** careful about this with regard to Megillat Esther, but I don't know of any sources regarding it.

Comment: I assumed the OPs question was about the practice of ensuring the table is covered even in temporary situations such as with a Tallis. If your post is only about kavua usage you should probably clarify that

Comment: @DoubleAA Correct assumption. In my first senetcne I say that I have **always** seen it covered. You can assume that a "permanent" shulchan tends to use a cloth, often embroidered. A tallit tends to be used in a temporary place such as in a hotel or Shiva home. In a home, I have seen people insist that the shat"z use his own tallit (as there is no other) to cover the table, so, there is obviously some concern that it be covered.

Comment: +1 for the answer, itself. I do agree with @DoubleAA's question, though. This does warrant research. Additionally, I'd like to get a better sense of what is considered tashmish kedusha. Talmud Megillah provides a list, and I think they include tefillin. If that were true, almost every chair and bench in every shul would need to be buried. It would also place the question of how anyone could sit on them.

Comment: @DanF I believe my edit addressed that. Since the tables, chairs, etc. are not designated exclusively for tefillin, they don't become a *tashmish kedusha*.

Comment: @Ploni - Ambiguous "it" in the last sentence. I think you mean to say that the table / chair, etc. don't become tashmish kedusha. As it reads now, it  implies that the tallit is not a tashmish kedusha.

Comment: @DanF The "it" is referring to the cloth. Your question doesn't ask about *tefillin*, which is why I didn't include it in the answer.

Comment: @DanF As far as "what is considered *tashmish kedusha*", I think that should be a separate question.